$C^1$ and affine map

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ length-preserving map (i.e., preserving the length of curves). Then we have that $Df \in O(n)$ for every $x \in \mathbb R^n$. It follows that $f$ is globally orientation preserving or reversing and hence an affine map.

I don't understand first why we have that $Df \in O(n)$ and then how one can conclude that $f$ is an affine map. Many thanks for some help there!

Do you know how to prove that the line segment $AB$ is the shortest path between $A$ and $B$?

Yes, this I know

Then can you prove the claim under the assumption that $Df$ preserves lengths of vectors (show that $f$ maps lines to lines)?

But how can I use the fact that f is $C^1$?

First, let us verify that $Df_x\in O(n)$ for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$. Take a smooth unit speed curve $c: [0,1]\to \mathbb R^n$, $c(0)=x$, $c'(0)=u$, for instance the unit line segment  $x+ tu, t\in [0,1]$, where $u$ is a unit vector. Then for every $T\in [0,1]$, the length of $c|_{[0,T]}$ is given by the integral
$$
\ell(T)= \int_{0}^T |c'(t)|dt= \int_{0}^T dt = T. 
$$
Similarly, the length of the curve $C= f\circ c$ is
$$
L(T)=\int_{0}^T |C'(t)|dt= \int_{0}^T |D_{c(t)}f(c'(t))|dt. 
$$
By the assumption, the two lengths are equal. Therefore, the derivatives of these functions are also equal. The first derivative is, of course, $1$, and the second, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
|D_{c(0)}f(c'(0))|=|D_xf(u)|.
$$
Hence, the linear map $D_xf$ sends unit vectors to unit vectors, this, $D_xf\in O(n)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$. This proves the first claim.
In particular, by the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Now, take an open subset $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $f: U\to V=f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism (and $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$). Take a small line segment $[p,q]$ in $U$, so small that not only $f([p,q])\subset V$ but also the line segment $[f(p), f(q)]\subset V$. Of course, we have that the length of  $[p,q]$ is the same as the length of $f([p,q])$ and the latter is $\ge$ the length of $[f(p), f(q)]$. Taking the image of $[f(p), f(q)]$ under $f^{-1}|_V$, we obtain a path $c$ in $U$ connecting $p, q$ and having the same length as $[f(p), f(q)]$. But then the length of $c$ is $\le$ the length of the line segment $[p,q]$, which implies that $c$ is just a unit speed parameterization of $[p,q]$. Applying $f$ to $c$ we then conclude that $[f(p), f(q)]$ equals $f([p,q])$. Thus, $f$ sends short line segments to line segments (preserving their lengths).
I will leave it to you to verify that $f$ is locally an affine map: For every $x\in \mathbb R^n$ there exists a neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ such that $f$ restricts to an affine map $A_x$ on $W_x$. (It is a good exercise in linear algebra.) But then, due to connectedness of $\mathbb R^n$, all these affine maps $A_x$ are the same, hence, $f$ is an affine map. qed

Many thanks for your answer! I think there is a f missing in your derivatives, for instance we have $D_x(f(U))$ but I got the point. For the last part I thought to show if n a neighborhood we have that the derivative is constant but I should for sure use that $D_xf$ preserves the length of vectors.. The question is now how

@FrederickManfred: I corrected the typos. The argument left as an exercise does not use differentiability of $f$, just the fact that it sends short line segments to line segments of the same length.
